# ejabberd addition.js and style.css file not loaded in web admin

Tags: javascript, css, erlang, ejabberd

I download ejabberd source code in ubuntu and compiled 100% but when I login addition.js and style.css is not loaded in web admin.

Can anyone help me.

I have post this question in below link as well.

https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/3117

Comment: Looks like you are getting help over there at GitHub. Please consider not cross-posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check that your url has backslash at the end:

localhost:5280/admin -> localhost:5280/admin/ notice the / at the end.

I had the same issue.